# Write exif data to android video files

Tags: android, video-processing, exif, id3, android-video-player

I am extracting metadata information (Exif infor) by using Id3 library in android, but I am getting null pointer exception and getting null in log Message it is a reason because value in src_set is null .I am not getting why it is returning null. my code is :

```
    File src = new File(pathdata);
    MusicMetadataSet src_set = null;
    try {
        src_set = new MyID3().read(src);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } // read metadata

    if (src_set == null) // perhaps no metadata
    {
        Log.i("NULL", "NULL");
    }
    else
    {
    try{
    IMusicMetadata metadata = src_set.getSimplified();
    String artist = metadata.getArtist();  
    String album = metadata.getAlbum();  
    String song_title = metadata.getSongTitle(); 
    Number track_number = metadata.getTrackNumber(); 
    Log.i("artist", artist);
    Log.i("album", album);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File dst = new File(pathdata);
    MusicMetadata meta = new MusicMetadata("name");
    meta.setAlbum("Chirag");
    meta.setArtist("CS");
    try {
        new MyID3().write(src, dst, src_set, meta);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ID3WriteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  // write updated metadata




}
```